# How to assign property of a baseclass which is acted as a placeholder in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a base class for my control so that all the controls derived from this base class will raise the same event

```
public class TradeEnterControl: UserControl
{
    TradeData masterTrade;
    public TradeData MasterTrade
    {
        get
        {
            return masterTrade;
        }
        set
        {
            masterTrade = value;
        }
    }
    public delegate void TradeUpdateRoutedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public static readonly RoutedEvent TradeUpdateEvent;
    static TradeEnterControl()
    {
        TradeUpdateEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TradeUpdate", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(TradeUpdateRoutedEventHandler), typeof(TradeEnterControl));
    }
    #region Trade Update Event
    public event TradeUpdateRoutedEventHandler TradeUpdate
    {
        add
        {
            base.AddHandler(TradeUpdateEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.RemoveHandler(TradeUpdateEvent, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void RaiseTradeUpdateEvent()
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TradeUpdateEvent));
    }
}
```

So my control will inherit `TradeEnterControl`

```
public partial class CollRepoTradeEnterControl : TradeEnterControl
```

I did not redefine `MasterTrade` property.

In my XAML, I have `TradeEnterControl` as a placeholder, to be like this

```
<my:TradeEnterControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,3,3,3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="TradeEnterControl"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TradeUpdate="TradeEnterControl_TradeUpdate" />
```

During runtime, I assign `TradeEnterControl` as,

```
TradeEnterControl.Content = new CollRepoTradeEnterControl();
```

when I update `MasterTrade` property in my `CollRepoTradeEnterControl`, 
the `MasterTrade` property in `TradeEnterControl` remain to be `null`. I am not sure why, is that because the way I am assigning it as `TradeEnterControl.Content = new CollRepoTradeEnterControl();`? How can I make sure when `CollRepoTradeEnterControl` MasterTrade property is assigned, the MasterTrade property in `TradeEnterControl` also get assigned?

Additional:
when I set a break point here:

```
    private void TradeEnterControl_TradeUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SplitTradeControl.SplitEntryGroup.MasterTrade = ((TradeEnterControl)sender).MasterTrade;
    }
```

I found, the `sender` which is the `TradeEnterControl` `MasterTrade` property is `null`
 [image]

But hiding deep inside the tree I can see the `MasterTrade` property got assigned,

[image]

Comment: `MasterTrade` Property will not assign separately like for base and child. When it sets from child, it will directly set to the base. Where your getting that `MasterTrade` of `TradeEnterControl` is null?

Comment: @Sankarann from the code behind of `MainWindow.xaml` which contains the `TradeEnterControl`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm mistaken, but - are you setting the *Content* of that UserControl to be CollRepoTradeEnterControl, as opposed to setting the UserControl itself? If so - then, yes, you're not setting the property that you thought you were. The content of an element, and the element, are two distinct things.
If you are wanting to assign a new object to *be* that UserControl, then you could give it a name, and thus that element will be available to your code-behind class as an instance member of that name. But, that's messy and problematic. A better approach, is to have a bindable property refer to an object of this class. Instead of trying to assign something to your XAML-defined object, assign it to your view-model property and let WPF do it's thing.
Also, don't forget - for properties that need to remember what they are and point to the correct code, consider whether you need to define that as virtual.